# Can I merge a branch if I've pulled without rebasing?

Tags: git

I have a branch that I will need to merge back into dev at some point. I need to keep pulling changes from dev. Normally I would use a rebase instead of a normal pull so my commits are all neatly at the top of the commit tree.

My worry is that im having to resolve a lot of merge conflicts. If I pull without rebasing then the old commits will always be there to refer to, so there is a limit to how much work I can lose.

If I pull without rebasing as I go alone does this present any risk when I need to merge my branch back into dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely not. In fact, pulling is safer than a rebase (in that you have less merge commits which can contain hidden changes). The main reason one would prefer a rebase over a pull is to keep the revision tree as linear as possible.

There is no more or less risk of losing data for a pull than there is with a rebase. They are essentially the same, except for the ordering of commits (barring hidden changes in merge commits as I mentioned above).

I would argue that a pull is better than a rebase, because a merge-commit in a pull is simply resolution of conflicts (ideally) after you have made your effective change, while a rebase conflict resolution commit includes both effective changes *and* conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with merging back into `dev` instead of rebasing on top of it later, then you would resolve the merge conflicts exactly once, just as when you pull without rebasing (which is effectively a merge of `dev` into your branch).

If you eventually need to rebase on top of `dev` before pushing, then you will potentially have to re-resolve the merge conflicts unless you do `rebase -p` to preserve the merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the current answers are correct. However git does allow for this exact workflow (rebasing) and only solving the conflicts once.

Git rerere (stands for reuse recorded resolution) if you enable this option git will automatically resolve the merge with the historic information of when you did it the first time.